# Sylvester-Gallai-type theorem for quadratic polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, gt.geometric-topology, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

Let $F_1, F_2$ and $F_3$ be finites sets of irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x_0, \ldots, x_n]$ of degree at most $2$ such that $F_1 \cap F_2 \cap F_3 = \varnothing$ and for every $Q_1, Q_2$  from distinct sets there is a  polynomial $P$ in the remaining set such that $V(Q_1, Q_2) \subseteq V(Q)$.

Is it true that $\text{trdeg}_{\mathbb{C}}(\cup_i F_i) = O(1)?$

This is a special case of Conjecture 1 [here](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2014/130/). Such questions are important for algebraic complexity.

It is more or less clear how to solve such question for polynomial of degree $1$ (see, for example,  https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.0330) however I have not intuition for quadratic polynomials.

Could you give some tools, ideas that can prove/disprove it?

Comment: What is the transcendence degree of a finite set of polynomials?

Comment: Zach Teitler, the  transcendence degree is the maximal number of algebraically independent polynomial in a set