# Linear homogenous polynomials that generates one quadratic polynomial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, complex-geometry, polynomials, algebraic-surfaces

Let $P_1, \ldots, P_m$, $Q_1, \ldots, Q_k \in \mathbb{C}[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ be linear homogenous polynomials. Let $f$ be a homogenous quadratic polynomial of degree $2$.

Assume that for every $i$ and for every $j$ the polynomial $f$ belongs to the ideal $\langle P_i, Q_j \rangle$.

Is it true that the rank of $\{P_1, \ldots, P_m \}$ (in the vector space of all linear polynomials $\mathbb{C}[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$)  or the rank of $\{Q_1, \ldots Q_k \}$ is less than some constant?

(I think the answer of this question can help to solve [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286922/sylvester-gallai-type-theorem-for-quadratic-polynomials) question)

**UPD**(First I asked this question for $f=x_0^2$ and Zach Teitler answered to it.)

I think I have understood my question better:).

It is not difficult to see that $f \in \langle P_i, Q_j \rangle \Leftrightarrow$ for every $x$ in subspace $\{t\in \mathbb{C}^n | P_i(t)=Q_j(t)=0\}$, $f(x)=0$.

So, we can ask some another **question**.

Let $M$ be 
a quadratic surface (the zeros of $f$). Assume that $M$ contains some finite set of subspaces of codimension $2$. What can we say about this set of subspaces? Can this set be large?

Comment: all the non-degenerate quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^n$ have the same geometry - so yes, you will be lots of subspaces on it. In the degenerate cases it's also true, as you will have the kernel and the complement, and you build subspaces...

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Do you mean that I can consider $f = x_0^2 + \ldots x_n^2$ consider subspaces that contained this $f$ and then ask is it possible to set these subspace by some $P_1, \ldots P_m$ and $Q_1, \ldots, Q_k$?

Comment: the classical example in $\mathbb{P}^3$ is given by the equation $x_0x_1=x_2x_3$.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik yes, but I need to consider $\mathbb{P}^n$ since I want to prove or disprove that some dimension is less than constant.

Comment: I meant to say that in $\mathbb{P}^3$ you have a  nondegenerate  example with infinitely many codimension 2 subspaces. Now you can build examples in any dimension $3+k.$ Just add $k$ more variables, and keep the same equation.  I.e. your quadric is still of rank 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will assume that $f$ is irreducible (if $f$ is not irreducible then in fact the argument of Zach Teitler's answer works).

Consider $M:= f \cap P_1$ (I mean the intersection of the zeros $f$ and $P_1$).

This set is the zeros of a quadratic form in plane $P_1$ of codimension $1$ (it can not be $P_1$ since $f$ is irreducible). For every $i$ the intersection of $Q_i$ and $f$ must contain a subspace of codimension $2$. Hence $M$ is the union of one or two subspace of codimension $2$. So, there exists at most $2$ subspace of codimension $2$ such that every $Q_i$ must contain at least one of them. Now, it is not difficult to see that rank of $\{Q_1, \ldots, Q_k\}$ is bounded by $4$. The similar argument works for the rank of $\{P_1, \ldots, P_m\}$.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the updated bottom part of the question. The nondegenerate quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^{2m-1}$ (i.e. in the case $n=2m$) are all equivalent to the quadric given by $f_{2m-1}:=\sum_{k=0}^{m-2}x_{k}x_{2m-1-k}=0$, and in $\mathbb{P}^{2m}$ (i.e. in the case $n=2m+1$) they are equivalent to the quadric given by $f_{2m}=f_{2m-1}+x_{2m}^2$.
The maximal dimension of a subspace on such a quadric $f$ equals $m$,  and there is infinitely many of them: the orthogonal group $O(f)$, which is isomorphic to the matrix group $\{A\in GL(n)\mid AA^\top=I\}$ has either one or two orbits on such subspaces (called maximal totally isotropic subspaces). Each subspace on the quadric lies in a maximal totally isotropic subspace.

Moreover, any quadric $M$ in $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$, then it is equivalent to a quadric given by either by $g:=f_{2m}$ or by $g:=f_{2m-1}$ for some $m<n/2$. The maximal subspaces on it are direct sums of the kernel of $M$ and a maximal totally isotropic subspace of $g$. Thus in particular as soon as there is one codimension 2 subspace in $M$, there is infinitely many of them there.

There are many sources where this can be found, e.g. the classic book [La géométrie des groupes classiques](https://books.google.ee/books?id=AfYZAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y) by Dieudonné (translated in many languages).

Answer (score 1):

Each ideal $\langle P_i, Q_j \rangle$ is a radical ideal. So in fact $x_0 \in \langle P_i, Q_j \rangle$. That means that $x_0 \in \operatorname{span}(P_i,Q_j)$. This holds for each $i,j$.

*Case 1.* Every $P$ is a scalar multiple of $x_0$, or every $Q$ is, or both. Then clearly the $P$'s have rank at most $1$, or the $Q$'s do, or both.

*Case 2.* Without loss of generality $P_1$ is linearly independent of $x_0$ and so is $Q_1$. Then every $Q$ is in the span of $P_1$ and $x_0$, so the $Q$'s have rank at most $2$; and every $P$ is in the span of $Q_1$ and $x_0$, so the $P$'s also have rank at most $2$. But they can't both have rank $2$. If they did, the $P$'s plus $x_0$ would have the same span as the $Q$'s plus $x_0$. Say this $2$-dimensional subspace has basis $x=x_0$ and $y$. Then $y$ is one of the $P$'s, or a linear combination of them anyway. And it is also a linear combination of the $Q$'s. But $x_0 \notin \langle y,y \rangle$.

No doubt there's a smoother argument, but in any case it follows that the $P$s or the $Q$s (or both) have rank $1$.

**Update.** I'm not sure if this idea is right, but: If $f \in \langle P_i, Q_j \rangle$ for every $i,j$, then it means $V(P_i,Q_j) \subset V(f)$. The union of those codimension $2$ subspaces is in fact $V(P_1 \dotsm P_m, Q_1 \dotsm Q_k)$! So by Nullstellensatz, there is some power $f^\ell \in \langle P_1 \dotsm P_m, Q_1 \dotsm Q_k \rangle$. Now that should be a radical ideal, if the $V(P_i,Q_j)$s are pairwise distinct subspaces, but it's very late at night here, so I don't know, I might be overlooking something. If it's right that $f$ is in that ideal, then in order to generate a quadratic form it must be the case $m \leq 2$ or $k \leq 2$. So... are you assuming much of anything about the $P$s and $Q$s? You haven't stated explicitly that they are pairwise distinct, let alone any other properties like any $n+1$ are linearly independent, etc. Is it possible that some $P_i=Q_j$, or anything like that?